# HTTPS requests are sent without headers with Python's Requests

Tags: python, https, http-headers, python-requests

I'm coding a little snippet to fetch data from a web page, and I'm currently behind a HTTP/HTTPS proxy. The requests are created like this:

```
headers = {'Proxy-Connection': 'Keep-Alive',
       'Connection':None,
       'User-Agent':'curl/1.2.3',
       }
r = requests.get("https://www.google.es", headers=headers, proxies=proxyDict)
```

At first, neither HTTP nor HTTPS worked, and the proxy returned 403 after the request. It was also weird that I could do HTTP/HTTPS requests with `curl`, fetching packages with `apt-get` or browsing the web. Having a look at Wireshark I noticed some differences between the `curl` request and the Requests one. After setting `User-Agent` to a fake `curl` version, the proxy instantly lets me do HTTP requests, so I supposed the proxy filter requests by `User-Agent`.

So, now I know why my code fails, and I can do HTTP requests, but the code keep on failing with HTTPS. I set the headers the same way as with HTTP, but after looking at Wireshark, no headers are sent in the CONNECT message, so the proxy sees no `User-Agent` and returns an ACCESS DENIED response.

I think that if only I could send the headers with the CONNECT message, I could do HTTPS requests easily, but I'm breaking my head around how to tell Requests that I want to send that headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I found a way after looking at `http.client`. It's a bit lower level than using Requests but at least it work.

```
def HTTPSProxyRequest(method, host, url, proxy, header=None, proxy_headers=None, port=443):
    https = http.client.HTTPSConnection(proxy[0], proxy[1])
    https.set_tunnel(host, port, headers=proxy_headers)
    https.connect()
    https.request(method, url, headers=header)
    response = https.getresponse()
    return response.read(), response.status

# calling the function
HTTPSProxyRequest('GET','google.com', '/index.html', ('myproxy.com',8080))
```